# Porque se diz "Semilha" na Ilha da Madeira para referir batata?

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-europeu, origem-histórica, regionalismo

Porque se diz "Semilha" na Ilha da Madeira para referir batata?

Muito utilizado pelos locais.

Quando é frita já dizemos "batata frita" e não "semilha frita"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicação encontrada em vários lugares e no [Cyber Dúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/semilha/16717), que por usa vez, menciona o [Elucidário Madeirense](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elucid%C3%A1rio_Madeirense)

> Trancrevemos o que sobre a palavra semilha se regista no Elucidário
>   Madeirense, do padre Fernando Augusto da Silva e de Carlos Azevedo
>   Meneses (2.ª edição mandada fazer pela então Junta Geral do Distrito
>   Autónomo do Funchal, 1946, Funchal), no Volume Terceiro:
>
> «Semilha. Este nome, dado na Madeira ao 'Solanum tuberosum', planta da
>   família das Solanáceas, deriva da palavra espanhola "semilla", que
>   parece ter sido escrita numa etiqueta que acompanhou os primeiros
>   tubérculos que vieram para esta ilha, importados das Canárias, e que
>   foi tomada aqui como o nome da planta. A semilha começou a ser
>   cultivadana Madeira em 1760, e multiplica-se por meio dos seus
>   tubérculos fraccionados, devendo cada fragmento conter alguns olhos.
>   Três ou quatro meses depois de terem sido plantados os tubérculos,
>   procede-se à colheita da produção.  A Madeira produz anualmente cerca
>   de 25 milhões de quilogramas de semilhas, podendo calcular-se em 10
>   000 quilogramas o rendimento médio por hectare (1921).  A semilha é
>   cultivada também no Porto Santo, onde só foi introduzida um pouco
>   depois de 1820.  Esta planta é oriunda dos Andes, na América
>   Meridional, e foi trazida à Europa pelos espanhóis, logo depois da
>   conquista do Peru. Associada a qualquer outra substância mais rica do
>   que ela em princípios azotados, constitui um alimento excelente para o
>   homem, e pode também ser utilizada tanto crua como cozida no sustento
>   dos animais.»

Encontrei também em outros lugares dizendo que o saco vinha escrito em espanhol: *Semilla de Patata* (Semente de Batata) no saco. Os madeirenses começaram a chamar de Semilha, enquanto que em Portugal continental de Batata. Também encontrei que a definição de Batata na Madeira seria apenas para a Batata Doce.

Comment: Exacto, a Batata é utilizada para definir a Batata Doce

Comment: De referir que, o termo semilha é utilizado muitas vezes, assim como, o termo Batata, para referir Batata. Esta situação gera dúvidas se a designação final é batata doce ou a batata.